# How to access Enum values in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I have an interface:

```
export interface Person {
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  status?: Status;
}

export enum Status {
  Single,
  Married,
  Divorced
}
```

if I create a Person

```
Person john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    status: Status.Married,
}
```

And I decide to access John's status by

```
var johnStatus = john.status;
```

I would get a number (1)

How do I make it so that I get the actual values (Single, Married, and Divorced) instead of a number? I am very new to typescript and it doesn't seem like there are a lot of info on this online. I tried adding keyword such as 'typeof' or 'keyof' but they don't work. Is there any other keywords I can use. Do I need to create a helper method? I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export enum Status {
  Single,
  Married,
  Divorced
}


//to string
const str1 = Status[Status.Single];
console.log(str1); // "Single"
// var johnStatus = Status[john.status];
```

or you can do

```
// STRING Enums
export enum Status {
  Single = 'Single',
  Married = 'Married',
  Divorced = 'Divorced'
}

const str2 = Status.Single;
console.log(str2); //"Single"
// var johnStatus = john.status;
```